# Driver box issue

Tags: light-fixture, light

We just installed two ultra slim recessed lights with driver boxes, they were working fine, but now they are not.

We checked the lights, they are working in other outlets, and we have power to the switch but no power from driver boxes to outlets.

Are there fuses inside that have blown for some reason, what could be the issue?

We are not sure if there is something we need to reboot inside the driver box?

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: More info is needed.  An explanation of how you installed them, a make and model # of the new fixtures, what other lights or outlets are on the same circuit.  More info is needed.

Comment: What make and model are these fixtures?